# Income requirement for Columbian TP-7 visa

Tags: visa, colombia, long-stay

One source says proof of income three times Columbia's minimum wage/salary.  That works out to under five hundred US dollars per month.

InternationalLiving.com says it's $717.

"[retire in the caribbean](https://www.retireinthecaribbean.com/)" says it was $970 in 2014.

"[Wrong Way Corrigan](https://blogs.eltiempo.com/wrong-way-corrigan/2017/03/10/applying-for-colombias-tp-7-independent-visa/)" says fifteen times minimum.

It seems unlikely that minimum wage would be reduced, and another source says it has not changed since 2016.

https://www.colombiavisas.com/colombia-visas/ says Colombian visas will be completely redesigned October of this year but provides NO details.

**What is the actual requirement to stay a year with possibility of renewal for a retired person not intending to work or study?  Official source?**

(If it matters, US citizen)

Comment: I suppose you're aware of this, but it seems worthwhile to mention explicitly that apparent reductions in the minimum wage could well be a result of the changing exchange rate.  See https://www.xe.com/currencycharts/?from=COP&to=USD&view=10Y. It looks like the exchange rate has changed by roughly a factor of 2 since 2014, which is consistent with your calculation of "just under $500" and the source saying it was $970 in 2014.

Comment: Actually, I looked up the minimum wage in Colombian pesos (COP) and converted.  But you've explained the $970, and if the $717 blurb is old enough, it might explain that, too.  Post as answer?   In my notes, I have the COP amount, so I can re-convert at any time.  I also (after posting) found a government document that confirmed the "three times" requirement.  But its next paragraph was incomprehensible, and said fifteen times!